# How to get exit code of process, that finishes before wait in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing bash script and have the situations when process finishes with error before wait in the following example code:

```
./process <params> &
PID=$!
wait $PID
```

And `wait $PID` gives me zero. How can i get the real exit code of background process in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works as expected, `./process` exited with zero. Zero is the "real exit code of background process in this situation". Substitute `./process <params>` for `exit <num>` and you can test it, ex. `exit 42 & PID=$! ; wait $PID ; echo $?` will print `42`.

Answer (score 0):

The real exit code is stored in `$?` after `wait` finishes. Therefore, `0` is already the correct exit code.

```
#! /bin/bash

function _exit_0 {
        sleep 2
        exit 0
}

function _exit_1 {
        sleep 2
        exit 1
}

_exit_0 &
wait $!
echo $?

_exit_1 &
wait $!
echo $?
exit 0
```

Output:

```
$ ./tmp.sh 
0
1
```